# How to disable checking Javadoc comments for class?

Tags: java, checkstyle

I have a checkstyle validation rule configured in my project. Configuration for checking Javadoc comments is looks like:

```
    <module name="JavadocType">
        <property name="scope" value="public"/>
        <property name="tokens" value="INTERFACE_DEF, ENUM_DEF"/>
    </module>
```

So, how can you see I just want to check javaDoc over interfaces and enums, but during execution

> error: Missing a Javadoc comment

is occurs, exactly over class declaration. Although I have no **CLASS_DEF** value in my module with name **JavadocType**.

Is there a possibility to disable checking javadoc comments over class declaration?

Comment: You sure the warning is on the class, or could it be a method also?

Comment: Yes, I am sure, the warning is on the class.

Comment: Then you are seeing a bug. This should work.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with the latest checkstyle version. Please make sure your version is 6.12 or later. Please supply us with a sample to be able to reproduce the problem to confirm it is a bug. See http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/report_issue.html#How_to_report_a_bug .

Comment: @rveach thank you for pointing me to the right version! We use **maven-checkstyle-plugin 2.17** and it by default uses **Checkstyle 6.11.2**. After changing version to **7.8** all works fine.